# Two Modal popup; passing id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

EDIT:

I narrow down the problem and i found that if I have: plain input tag without MVC RAZOR then it work as expected

```
<input type="text" class="hiddenid2" /> //WORKED
```

but if i have : (does not work)

```
 @Html.Editor("id", "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "hiddenId2" } })
```

or

```
 @Html.Editor("id", "", new { @class = "hiddenId2"  })
```

then it does not work

END UPDATE

This is driving me crazy after going through line by line and everything seems correct but I'm not sure what else do I need to do here.

The problem I'm having is:

I'm passing the Id to the modal popup so I have two modal popup with different Ids & class name. The First modal popup works and it does pass the Id to modal popup but the second modal popup does not pass the id.

First Modal:

//View Link

```
<a href="/Home/Employee/@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
class="modalLink">Load Employee</a>
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Employee", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 @Html.Hidden("id", "", new { @class = "hiddenid" })
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(.modalLink").click(function () {
     var passedID = $(this).data('id');
     $('#id').val(passedID);
     $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
});
```

Second Modal:

//View Link

```
<a href="/Home/Employer/@item.Id" data-id="@item.Id" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" 
class="modalLink2">Load Employer</a>
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Employer", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                 @Html.Hidden("id", "", new { @class = "hiddenid" })
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(.modalLink2").click(function () {
     var passedID = $(this).data('id');
     $('#id').val(passedID);
     $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your selector. Both modals contains the same $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);  this will always operate on the first .modal-body .hiddenid jquery finds, and this is indeed always the hidden input in your first modal.

you can perform a quick fix by changing the class name of the 2nd modal.

HEre is a running [example on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOKdva)

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="/Home/Employee/@item.Id" data-id="id-number-one" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
class="modalLink">Load Employee</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Record</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                   <input type="text" class="hiddenid"/>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->




<br>
<a href="/Home/Employer/@item.Id" data-id="id-number-two" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" 
class="modalLink2">Load Employer</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Record</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" class="hiddenid2"/>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JS:

```
$(".modalLink").click(function () {
    var passedID = $(this).data('id');
     $('#id').val(passedID);
     $(".modal-body .hiddenid").val(passedID);
});

$(".modalLink2").click(function () {
     var passedID = $(this).data('id');
     $('#id').val(passedID);
     $(".modal-body .hiddenid2").val(passedID);
});
```

Comment: what exactly you have changed in your code? and i did change the class name to `.modal-body2` but i do not see any diff, still the same not populating the code ... the one you have in a CodePen is the static and i'm dealing with dynamic ids

Comment: @AbuHamzah, the key lies with what jquery selector and classname you are using. the change I have made is to give the hidden input a classname of hiddenid2 (you gave both hidden inputs an class of hiddenid).  Additionally you can click on the codepen link again. Play around with it. I have added labeling to make it clear

Comment: you might think i'm crazy but its not working and when i looked at the source of my page and its rendering my input as `<input class="text-box single-line" id="id" name="id" type="text" value="" />` i have no idea whats going on and even though my first modal is working without any issue and i did have .hidden2 for the second modal arggg

Comment: @AbuHamzah can you paste your code in codepen/jsfiddle. leave the razor code in there, it's fine. I'll take a look for you

Comment: @AbuHamzah  what html does your current (not working) razor code render

Comment: razor code rendering and i think the problem is razor code is not rendering correctly the class name so its not finding class... thats what i have noticed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83143/discussion-between-ji-in-coding-and-abu-hamzah).

Answer (score 0):

@Ji_in_coding: helps me to narrow down the reason why the id was not passing and I was able to provide both `class and id`

I able to fix by adding id and class

```
@Html.Hidden("id", "", new { @class = "hiddenid2", id = "hiddenid2" })
```